# PyCharm import psycopg2 package: there is error:

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, importerror

I wanted to use the project interpreter import the psycopg2 package as shown in figure 1 and 2.

[image: [python 3.5]

[image: import the psycopg2 package]

but there are errors, firstly, I should add something, I have used the brew to install the PostgreSQL in the terminal (python 2.7 version). I have also installed the python3.5 in the Library file as showed in the figure1.

but the error is displayed as showed in their figure 2, I am new one to Pycharm. could you help me to deal with it! Thanks!

[image: error output1]

[image: error output1]

I have installed the python3.5, but the terminal default is python 2.7 I have installed the psycopg2==2.6.1 in the terminal. But the PyCharm used the python3.5 version. I don't know how to install the psycopg2==2.6.1 under the python3.5 version, but the terminal is default is python2.5. Thanks

I have run the command as mentioned by the  answer. 
you can checked the figure .

[image: run the command as mentioned by the answers]

But there is still error(please check the bottom), although I have installed the library followed by this link. Could you give me hand to deal with this. I am a little confused with this tool(Pycharm).
http://quabr.com/27422248/error-adding-import-lettuce-on-pycharm
[image: errors: used import statment]

Unused import statement:

Unused import statement..." and then: "this inspection detects names that should resolved but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items".

Answer (score 1):

pg_config is not visible. Did you install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

? If yes maybe directory with pg_config is not on on PATH.

As the notice says, try to execute:

```
pip install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

in shell and if it goes wrong check with

```
echo $PATH
```

do you have a pg_config available. If not, then that's the thing you need to fix first.

Another thing to check, if you want to have psycopg2 available for python3.x try:

```
pip3 install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

Comment: I have installed the python3.5, but the terminal default is python 2.7 I have installed the psycopg2==2.6.1 in the terminal.  But the PyCharm used the python3.5 version. I don't know how to install the  psycopg2==2.6.1 under the python3.5 version, but the  terminal is default is python2.5. Thanks

Comment: Hey there. Is this what you want to achieve: to have different python version executing project in pycharm and shell?

Comment: Thanks! The Pycharm use the python3, I don't know how to install the psycopg2==2.6.1, although I have installed the psycopg2==2.6.1 in the terminal(default python 2.7).

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer @ Pawel Bec. I have followed your comments, as showed in  figure(I have edited my question), and there is still errors: Used import statement: Unresolved reference lettuce..." and then: "this inspection detects names that should resolved but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items". I am not good at the shell command, and new with pycharm, I am sorry to give you trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Beca， I solved it, if the numpy package is not used in the code, the warning will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pawel Beca， I solved it, if the numpy package is not used in the code, the warning will be displayed. After I used in the code, the warning will be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the exact same issue, however I was sure that i was already in python 3.7, but trying to install psycopg2 version 2.7.3.1 was getting your error. What fixed this for me was trying to install 2.7.5. Went in no problem